# Link shared library scons

Tags: dynamic, shared, scons, .so

How do i link a shared library (versioned) for eg. libabc.so.10 in sconscript ?

As per this link i have to specify the library in LIBS= [ ]
http://scons.org/doc/2.3.0/HTML/scons-user/x667.html

I tried using LIBS= [ 'abc' ] but getting a linker error, cannot find the library
however if i rename libabc.so.10 to libabc.so, it works fine and I am able to get the executable but when i run the executable it, get error as below

./helloabc: error while loading shared libraries: libabc.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Typically you'd symlink libabc.so.10 to libabc.so, not rename, which should solve this - it'll link against the symlink but still be able to load the original name later. However I guess that's just a work-around: I don't know the correct way to configure linking against a specific version in the linker.

Comment: Likely if you only have libabc.so.10 that means you've not installed the devel version of the package which would also include header files and the symlink..